# preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found in regax of laravel validation

Tags: laravel, validation

Why is this regex pattern is wrong?
`'url' => 'regex:/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu.be|youtube.com(?:\/embed\/|/v\/|\/watch\?v=))([\w-]{10,12})/'`
How to solve this in laravel validation regex? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See here list of Laravel [helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers)

There is no helper that will help you.
Use php function [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match)

You can test your expression [here](https://www.phpliveregex.com/)